# Posterior Predictive Checking

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I'm relatively new at all this. I've performed an imputation on metabolomics data, and another colleague has queried the quality of my imputation (I performed predictive mean matching using MICE in R.)

Having looked into this, there isn't any official way to assess imputation beyond visually assessing the imputed and observed data. I've found some papers on using posterior predictive checking and p-value comparing whether the complete data is more extreme than the observed, but as I'm new to this I feel attempting to write the codes without guidance to be too challenging at this point.

Can anyone direct me to an example script, or perhaps a well described command, in the program R which will enable me to perform sufficient checks on my imputation?

Thank you, K.

Comment: Not an expert here, but I generally try this when building a classifier:
1. Subset the data containing all complete cases: `complete.cases`
2. Introduce some `NA`s into the data: Try `missForest::prodNA`
3. Try imputing these `NA`s using the same imputation method
4. Use the imputed and the original (complete subset) data to build 2 classifiers and check results on test/cross validation data
5. If results for imputed data are comparable, use the same method

This is a hit and trial method, but gives a pretty good indication if the imputation method is suitable for your data

Comment: The method of subsetting to complete cases and then performing a simulated imputation makes sense. But would you be able explain what a classifier is?

Comment: Classifier is basically just a function that takes data as input and outputs a single value, known as the class(category) of the input. For example, if I need to check whether or not a mail is spam, I will covert the mail to some input vector, feed it to the classifier, the classifier will return a single value which will tell me whether or not a mail is spam. It is not really relevant to the question, You could just use the method I described and ignore this part. You did not mention what purpose you were using the data for, so I took an example of a classifier...